# In Oracle SQL developer how do you insert date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am Unable to insert date data and time data into oracle table. Please find the below query and error

```
INSERT INTO Sunday_Service (
    Service_ID,
    Service_date,
    Start_time,
    End_time,
    Service_location,
    No_of_children)
Values (
    Seq_service_id.nextVal,
    TO_DATE('YYYY-MM-DD', '2022-07-03'),
    TO_DATE('hh24:mi:ss', '09:00:00'), 
    TO_DATE('hh24:mi:ss', '10:15:00'),
    'RM 2101',
    '10');
```

error:

[Error report ORA-01821](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj1r3.png)

Comment: If the columns are already date format, then you don't need to convert them during your insert statement. Just say values (1, '2022-07-03', '09:00:00', '10:15:00', '5','6')

Comment: @Isolated - that is relying on implicit conversion and conflicting NLS settings - you can't implicitly convert 2022-07-03 and 09:00:00 to dates with the same `NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. And generally shouldn't rely on implicit conversion anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the info. I've only used combined datetime fields so wasn't entirely sure that would work anyway. Good to know.

Comment: You need to take a step back and read again about the `date` data type in Oracle SQL, which may be different from other dialects you may have worked with in the past. In Oracle SQL, a `date` value always has a "date" **and** a "time-of-day" component, so the way you split that across two columns makes no sense. If you only give a "date", it will have the "time-of-day" assigned as 00:00:00 by default. If you only give a time-of-day (hh:mi:ss), then the "date" part is assigned the value of the first day of the current month by default. Neither makes sense for your use case; combine them.

Answer (score 3):

You have your parameters switched in your `TO_DATE` function calls. Your `TO_DATE` function calls should look like this:

```sql
TO_DATE ('2022-07-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_DATE ('09:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'),
TO_DATE ('10:15:00', 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `to_date()` the wrong way around:

```
INSERT INTO Sunday_Service (Service_ID, Service_date, 
                            Start_time, End_time, 
                            Service_location, No_of_children)
VALUES (Seq_service_id.nextVal,
        TO_DATE('2022-07-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
        TO_DATE('09:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'),
        TO_DATE('10:15:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'), 
        'RM 2101',
        '10');
```

But you probably want to combine the time and date, rather than holding them in separate columns; so if you removed `service_date` from your table you could do:

```
INSERT INTO Sunday_Service (Service_ID,
                            Start_time, End_time, 
                            Service_location, No_of_children)
VALUES (Seq_service_id.nextVal,
        TO_DATE('2022-07-03 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
        TO_DATE('2022-07-03 10:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'RM 2101',
        '10');
```

Apart from anything else, that will make it possible to handle service calls that span midnight or multiple days.

You could also use timestamp literals:

```
...
VALUES (Seq_service_id.nextVal,
        TIMESTAMP '2022-07-03 09:00:00', 
        TIMESTAMP '2022-07-03 10:15:00', 
...
```

or slightly more explcitly:

```
...
VALUES (Seq_service_id.nextVal,
        CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-07-03 09:00:00' AS DATE), 
        CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-07-03 10:15:00' AS DATE), 
...
```

If `no_of_children` is a number column, as it appears, then the last value should be a number - `10` rather than `'10'`.